# GWT vPanel.clear() javascriptException

Tags: gwt

When I call vPanel.clear() I get:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl::apply(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)([JavaScript object(1768), JavaScript object(1767), JavaScript object(1772)]): Object [object global] has no method 'removeChild'
```

It also happens in FireFox, some articles suggested it was an Chrome issue.
Longer version how it happens is: I do `vPanel.clear()` then `vPanel.add(flowPanel)` then remove `flowPanel` with `DOM.getElementById(id).removeFromParent()` and then try to add an element again. This action will fetch data from server and before drawing the data will call vPanel.clear() and then the error appears.

Has anyone seen this problem before? And whats the real issue here, why doesn't clear work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should not mix the low-level DOM-API and the widget-API. You can remove with http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/VerticalPanel.html#remove(com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Widget)

Comment: Thanks! This with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957388/get-widget-by-id-in-gwt gave me the answer :)