# Capture callback after uploading files using HTML form

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, forms, blobstore

I am using GWT to upload files to the Blobstore.
I am using `FormElement uploadForm` that represents the `<form>` that is used to upload the file. After the `uploadForm.submit()` I need to wait on the same page and capture the callback when the file is correctly uploaded, so that I can place its path on the client code.

How can I do that? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use [`FormPanel`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.html) instead. You are very limited functions with `FormElement` That gives  to handle many events.

```
 formpanel.addSubmitCompleteHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitCompleteHandler() {
      public void onSubmitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event) {
        // When the form submission is successfully completed, this event is
        // fired. Assuming the service returned a response of type text/html,
        // we can get the result text here (see the FormPanel documentation for
        // further explanation).
        Window.alert(event.getResults());
      }
    });
```

You can even capture the event just before to submit even with that

```
 form.addSubmitHandler(new FormPanel.SubmitHandler() {
      public void onSubmit(SubmitEvent event) {
        // This event is fired just before the form is submitted.
```

Update:  To use `FormPanel` with HTML element (haven't tested)

Step 1 : get `Element` by Id `DOM.getElementById("")`

Step 2: prepare widget with it : [get widget by id in gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957388/get-widget-by-id-in-gwt)

Step 3: :`formPanel.setWidget(thatWidget);`

Comment: Thanks. The form code is directly in html. That is why I use FormElement, retrieving the html form from its id. Is there another way?

Comment: Then you need some javascript/jquery. That is strange that you are using still HTML and wrapping around with GWT ^^?

Comment: Is there a way to create a FormPanel and place it inside an exising html《div id=myContainer"》that can be accesed via getElementById ()?

Comment: Updated , Hope that helps.